# Need help on Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent

How are you all? New on Intent and do not know much about it. I have two activities. First activity has a button to start second activity. Here is how:

```
 private void main_button_start_from_long_clicklistener()
```

{

```
  main_button_start_from.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
  {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View vlc)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        intent_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),startfrom.class);
        startActivity(intent_main);
        return false;
    }

  });
```

}

Now second activity has an Edittext to take input and send to first activity to display. Here is the code:

```
 edittext_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

 edittext_input.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener()
     {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            {
                string_start_from_input = edittext_input.getText().toString();
                   intent_start_from_input = new Intent();
                   intent_start_from_input.putExtra("input-value", string_input_start_from);
                   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_start_from_input);
                   finish();
            return false;
            }

        }

     });
```

And first activity has also:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUNCTION)
          if(requestCode == RESULT_OK)
          {
              string_input = data.getStringExtra("input_value");
          }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now how to display the String on first activity in

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
.....
 startActivityForResult(?, REQUEST_CODE_FUNCTION);
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main_button_start_from_long_clicklistener` change the `startActivity(intent_main);` to `startActivityForResult(intent_main, 0);`

And than override the `onActivityResult` in your first activity. see [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Comment: Thankyou Ralph Begmann. Now onActivityResult has three variables, int ,int, intent. What values to put here?  Little bit confused here. Please  help.

Comment: please read the documentation, it's all there http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities